# How to alter sort handler to keep existing order intact in views

Tags: views, hooks

I created a `views` page using `foo` plugin.When a user visit the page the **city** and **Clinic/Hospital** columns by default are being rendered **alphabetically (ASC)** as in below screenshot.

**EDIT:** Let's say for example. **City** is Bangalore and only for Bangalore **Clinic/Hospital(C/H) column** is alphabetically ordered(say Hospitals A,B,C,D...).Then user **clicks on City head**,then for Bangalore **C/H column is alphabetically disordered(ex B,D,C,H...) but records are still correct to Bangalore city means those clinic/hospitals are located in Bangalore** .Same goes for other cities too.What I want is C/H col should be ordered as earlier (alphabetical) City by City but no matter how city is ordered.

[image]

When user clicks on **City** head (which is **sortable**),the order of **Clinic/Hospital** goes heywire (no more alphabetical order) like below image:

[image]

**Problem:** How can I make my **Clinic/Hospital** order intact even after user clicks on **City** head.

Below is my `views` configuration:
[image]

I am using `Drupal 7.41` and `views 3.0`

**Tried so far:**

```
function mymodule_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
   if($view->name == 'list_of_doctors' && $view->current_display == 'page_1' && count($query->orderby) == 1)
    {

        $query->orderby[1] = array(
             'field' => 'field_data_field_clinic_hospital_field_clinic_hospital_value',
             'direction' => 'ASC',
            );
    }
 }
```

}

But after clicking **City** head,whole **table** vanishes.

Comment: This doesn't make sense; if you want to sort by city *and* keep the order of clinic/hospital intact, then you will not have the same information in rows anymore. How do you want to show the information in 1 row if there are 2 sort filters?

Comment: Please see my edit

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to be able to use a secondary sort after overriding the default sort by clicking on a column header.

This can be achieved from the front-end using [jQuery plugin TableSorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Demo) as described here:
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/125188/22915

Note this won't work for views with pagination.

It can also be achieved with some custom PHP code. Add the following to a custom module and change the CAPITALIZED words accordingly.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_query_alter().
 */
function YOUR_MODULE_NAME_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  if ($view->name === 'YOUR_VIEWS_NAME' && $view->current_display === 'YOUR_VIEWS_DISPLAY_NAME' && count($query->orderby) == 1) {
    $query->orderby[1] = array(
      'field' => 'YOUR_SECONDARY_SORT_FIELD',
      'direction' => 'ASC',
    );
  }
}
```

This code snippet will make sure that, no matter what column you use as main sorting, you always use a certain field as secondary sort. In your case this would be the Clinic/Hospital field (use system name in code).

Note: if the secondary sort field is not a sortable column, you can't use the query alias. So YOUR_SECONDARY_SORT_FIELD needs to be something like: 'field_data_field_name.field_name_value' instead of 'field_data_field_name_field_name_value'.

Comment: See my code above.

Comment: You should put your field name (field_data_field_clinic_hospital_field_clinic_hospital_value) in quotes.

Comment: Code corrected but it stopped sorting for City completely

Comment: Can you share the Views format 'footable' settings? And could you try with just a the 'normal' table formatter?
And can you dump what is in $query->orderby[0] when you click on the 'city' in the table header?

Comment: Pls refer: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BxTdmrByvIfKc1RQNkRRTTBEUlU&usp=sharing

Comment: In normal table it is also behaviour.I attached query preview to above link which happens after user clicks on City head.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful. 
Try to check: 'Overwrite normal sorting if click sorting is used' in the format settings.

Comment: When I check 'Overwrite....',it shows error in preview.Snapshot attached.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36267/discussion-between-dmsmidt-and-hiranya).